# q/KDB Selecting multiple symbols using functional select

Tags: kdb

I am trying to select multiple symbols using function select but it is throwing an error  :

```
d:([] s:5#`v`b ; p:5?10)
?[d;enlist (in;`s;(),`v`b);0b;()]
'b
```

however, when I select a single symbol, it returns correct data

```
?[d;enlist (in;`s;(),`v);0b;()]
s p
---
v 8
v 4
v 2
```

what exactly is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run parse on the equivalent q-sql expression you will see `,` in parse tree:

```
q)parse"select from d where s in`v`b"
?
`d
,,(in;`s;,`v`b)
0b
()
```

This means `enlist`, so if you sub that in instead the query should work:

```
q)?[d;enlist(in;`s;enlist`v`b);0b;()]
s p
---
v 8
b 1
v 9
b 5
v 4
q)?[d;enlist(in;`s;enlist`v);0b;()]
s p
---
v 8
v 9
v 4
```

Answer (score 4):

In the following query, you are not explicitly enlisting the values you want to search

```
?[d;enlist (in;`s;(),`v`b);0b;()]
```

Using `enlist` the multiple symbol will fix the query :

```
?[d;enlist (in;`s;enlist `v`b);0b;()]
```

When `enlist` is not used with the value(s) explicitly, KDB treats it as a column name and try to run the condition between the columns (like `columnA=columnB`)

The other query works because `()` is in a way enlisting the atom to list; this is the way `()` is different from `enlist`.

```
?[d;enlist (in;`s;(),`v);0b;()]
```

**() vs enlist**

In case of atoms , it archives the same result

```
q)(),`a
,`a
q)enlist `a
,`a
```

but it gives different results when used with a list

```
q)type (),`a`b
11h
q)type enlist `a`b
0h
```